# xamarin.auth with google UriFormatException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.auth

I want to login to google Account by xamarin.auth and follow [this Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth)
but i show this error System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'

when Run on Android device and ios simulator

**Update** =>

As @Jason Said {if you are getting an "invalid URI" exception, then it stands tor reason that one of your URI arguments is invalid.}

its my mistak i forgot to add {:/oauth2redirect}

Thank you @Jason
Thank you @Paul Kertscher

Comment: you need to show the relevant parts of your code

Comment: var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
    clientId,
    null,
    Constants.Scope,
    new Uri(Constants.AuthorizeUrl),
    new Uri(redirectUri),
    new Uri(Constants.AccessTokenUrl),
    null,
    true);

Comment: if you are getting an "invalid URI" exception, then it stands tor reason that one of your URI arguments is invalid.

Comment: @Jason thats right i forget {:/oauth2redirect} in the url thankyou

Comment: @Ezz You can *edit* your question. Please **do not** post updates as comments.

Comment: @Ezz :) When you found the answer to your question, please add it as an answer, this will help others experiencing the same (or a similar) issue.